# Erro de analisador na minha aplicação

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, webforms

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando rodar minha aplicação mas aparece este Erro do Analisador. Já entrei na webforms de Fornecedor para ver se encontro algum erro no código mas nada, compilo o projeto e da nada de erro.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Fornecedor.aspx.cs" Inherits="SoftwareSalgado.Paginas.Fornecedor" %>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você deve confirmar se o namespace está correto `SoftwareSalgado.Paginas`.  Depois, você precisa verificar se a classe `Fornecedor` é uma partial e está herdando `System.Web.UI.Page`.

Por último, mas não obrigatório, é interessante você implementar o o método `Page_Load` para inicializá-la e controlar o `PostBack`.

```
namespace SoftwareSalgado.Paginas
{
    public partial class Fornecedor : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Leandro, deu certinho.

Comment: @MarcoRibeiro Era esse mesmo o problema? Se a proposta é a resposta para a sua pergunta, é importante votar como útil e aceitar como resposta, assim a sua pergunta e a solução podem ser úteis para outros usuários que venham a enfrentar o mesmo problema